# Is there a WPF library to draw math expressions?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, math, wpf-controls

I'm looking for a WPF library within which you insert a string expression, and this can be represented in XAML. For example, if I write `(2)/(4)`, this should draw a fraction (it's just an example).

I really have no idea, and I have googled, and while I found many sites that suggested Bazaar, the links are broken. If you can point me to a library, it would be great.

I'm not looking for this to evaluate the expression, just to draw it in XAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just so happens that [there is](https://launchpad.net/wpf-math).